# Convert duplicate values to blank in column 1 and remove duplicates in column 2 for the value of column1

Tags: sql

[image: Data and Result]

In the above pic, in column 1 need to put blank when it is repeating and in column 2 only the data which is repeating next to column 1 should be eliminated.

The data in column 2 can be repeated if it is next to some other value. For example, FB60 can be repeated in column 2 once for Chicago, once for Detroit and once for Houston, but it cannot be repeated more than once for Chicago, (more than once for Detroit and more than once for Houston.

Sorry, the explanation is bit confusing, so let me know if you have difficulty in understanding so I can try to simply more for you.

Comment: Please tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: @Archit . . . I removed the extraneous database tags; feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.  Also, this type of manipulation is often done in the presentation layer, rather than the database.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff, one thing you could do in the SQL query is to issue a "distinct User_id, Action" in your query which will remove duplicates and then use the application layer to create the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT UserId, Action FROM tbl
    ) t
)
SELECT
    UserId  = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN c.UserId ELSE '' END,
    c.Action
FROM Cte c
ORDER BY c.UserId, c.rn
```

*Note: This should be done in the presentation layer instead.*